# Version number with git in Netbeans

Tags: java, git, netbeans, version

I am using Netbeans (and language is Java), and using git for versioning. I would like to give version number to my application for every commit in git.
Is it possible? I couldn't manage to do it.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Seems like a perfectly reasonable question and common practice. Not sure why this was down voted.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is technically possible, if you are doing your git commits, etc from the command line.  The Git book explains how to create tags ... http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging ... and you just need to create one with each commit.

However, this doesn't seem like a good idea to me.  Each git commit has a unique identifier, and creating a second one seems redundant.